# What is the order of execution of code in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, order-of-execution

How exactly is code in JavaScript executed? I mean in what order? Would there be a difference in the order of execution if I declared a function like this:

```
function render() {
    // Code here
}
```

instead of this:

```
var render = new function(){
    // Same code here
}
```

Does JavaScript execute functions that are defined in a scripting file regardless of whether they're called by an event handler? (e.g. `onload=function()`).

And finally if a function is defined in another function, when the parent function is called, is the lower function also called too? e.g.

```
function a(){

    function b(){
        // code
    }

    function c(){
        //code
    }

}
```

I'm trying to get a concrete understanding of order of execution in JavaScript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var render = new function(){
  // same code here
}
```

The `new` keyword doesn't create a new Function. It creates a new object by running the function. So this would actually run the body of the method and return an object instead.

If your **asking when are functions parsed** and added to scope then that's implementation specific, but all functions are hoisted to the top of scope and generally parsed before any code is executed.

Functions are  **only executed** when you call them by invoking `f()`

Answer (score 4):

A function declaration is hoisted (so it can be called earlier in the code then it is defined), a function statement isn't.

> Does JavaScript execute functions that are defined in a scripting file regardless of whether they're called by an event handler?

A function is called when it is called. Either because something has `theFunction` followed by `()` (possibly with arguments) or because it has been made an event handler.

> `onload="function"`

If that is JS, then it will assign a string to something expecting a function. If that is HTML, then you need `()` to call the function.

> And finally if a function is defined in another function, when the parent function is called, is the lower function also called too?

No. A function is only called when it is called. Declaring a function inside another one just limits its scope.

Answer (score 0):

When you declare a function, it is not executed until it's called (that's true for ones declared in onload and other events as well).

For nested functions, they are not executed automatically when the top-level function is called UNTIL the containing function calls them.